# WPF Basics: namespaces

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces

I have been scratching my head for a bit and I'm sure this is a obvious one but I just can't see it.

I made a new application "WpfApplication3"

I add a class "Person.cs":

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace WpfApplication3
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get { return "Jonas"; } }
        }
    }
```

And then I try this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:Person x:Key="somePerson"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding {StaticResource somePerson.Name}}"/>-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And I get the error "The name "Person" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication".

What am I doing wrong?

Using VS Express 2012 for windows desktop (trial).

Comment: I've tried it, and I have no problem to compile. Have you tried to compile twice? (Sometimes it helps with WPF (especially for custom and user controls)).

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange but I tested and sure enough it would not find Person.

Then I added a public ctor to Person

```
public class Person 
{
    public Person() { }
}
```

And it would compile

Now I can remove the ctor and it will (still) compile

Try (multiple) clean and rebuild

I know makes no sense but it happened to me